# Ruby Sequel gem: update a row column with a value from another row column that I know the Id

Tags: ruby, updates, sequel

How to write this using the Sequel gem? :

```
update table set col = (select col from table where id = :x) where id = :y
```

I have the record with `id=:y` but I want to avoid retrieving the record with `id(:x)` and then doing the *update*. Just one step!
Do I have to use *raw sql* (`DB.run()`)?

Comment: Seems like raw sql is your way)

Answer (score 3):

```
DB[:table].where(:id=>y).update(:col=>DB[:table].where(:id=>x).select(:col))
```

Comment: That's really nice! I'll try later. This will perform only one sql command, right?

Comment: BTW, I had to put this statement inside a transaction block to make it work ( `DB.transaction do ...  end` )

Comment: I had to rollback to my previous code. I had some trouble persisting the changes, even with a transaction block. Strangely, some runs didn't save changes.